# appending objects from child component to parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

How would I append an object from a child component to a parent components object?
Lets say I have a parent component like so:

```
const Parent = (props.data) = {
const data = [{}]

useEffect(() => {
 console.log(data)
}, [])

return (
 <View>
  <ChildComponent data={data} />
  <AnotherChildComponent data={data} />
 <View>
)
}
```

And here is the child component:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {

const data = useState(props.data)

useEffect(() => {
 //add value to data
 data.input = "This is Child Component input"
},[])

return (
 <View>
  <Text>{data.input}</Text>
 </View>
)
}
```

Then here is AnotherChildComponent:

````
const AnotherChildComponent = (props) => {

const data = useState(props.data)

useEffect(() => {
 //add value to data
 data.input = "This is another Child Component with a different input"
},[])

return (
 <View>
  <Text>{data.input}</Text>
 </View>
)
}```

Then in the parent component id have a function that logs data, the expected output should be:
````

```
{ input: "This is Child Component input" } 
{ input: "This is another Child Component with a different input" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `setData` function as a prop to the `children` of the parent and set the data or there or create a callback function.

Remark: create a state.

```js
const Parent = (props.data) = {
const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
 console.log(data)
}, [])

return (
 <View>
  <ChildComponent data={data} setData={setData} />
  <AnotherChildComponent data={data} setData={setData} />
 <View>
)
}
```

In ChildComponent.

```js
const ChildComponent = (props) => {

const [input, setInput] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
 const obj = {input: "This is ChildComponent input"}
 //add value to data for parent state
 setData(prev => [...prev, obj])
 // add value to child state for text
 setInput(obj)
},[])

return (
 <View>
  <Text>{obj.input}</Text>
 </View>
)
}
```

In another child.

```js
const AnotherChildComponent = (props) => {
const [input, setInput] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
 const obj = {input: "This is another child component with a different input"}

 //add value to data
 setData(prev => [...prev, obj])
 // add value to child state for text
 setInput(obj)
},[])

return (
 <View>
  <Text>{obj.input}</Text>
 </View>
)
}
```

Comment: cant find var: setData

Comment: would i have to say setData = props.setData?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Either `props.setData` or use destructuring `const ChildComponent = ({data, setData})`

Comment: this seems to break my text input in the child component, it also runs endlessly on a useEffect hook

Comment: If you want to view only the input in each individual AND set the state in the parent then you need two states. I have added this to my answer. The dependency array of the useEffect is empty. It only runs on mount once. If it runs endlessly for you, then your code differs from this example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use state in your parent component and a callback function which is passed with prop in your children components, here using hooks:

```
const Parent = () = {
const [data, setData] = useState([{}])
    
const addInput = useCallback((newInput)=>{
    setData((previousData)=>[...previousData,newInput])}
    ,[setData])
    
useEffect(() => {console.log(data)}, [])
        
return (
    <View>
        <ChildComponent data={data} addInput={addInput}/>
        <AnotherChildComponent data={data} addInput={addInput} />
    <View>
)
}
```

Your childComponent:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
        
const [input, setInput] = useState("")
        
const onChangeText= (text)=>{
setInput(text)
}
return (
         <View>
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            value={input}
          />
         <Button title="Add Input" 
                 onPress={()=>props.addInput({"input":input})}/>
         {props.data.map((data)=>{return(
         <Text>{data.input}</Text>

         )}}

         </View>
        )
}
```

Comment: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

Comment: It's probably due to the call you did in your children component

Comment: how should it look in the child comps?

Comment: For example for a button the prop onClick would be  `onClick={()=>props.addInput("newInput")}`

Comment: this seems to break my text input. if i type anything in it then dissapears. <TextInput onChangedText={txt => props.addInput(text)}/>